# Method calculations wrong when used in JTable, but correct when printed out in console

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a triangle program that I wrote as an assignment for my intro to JAVA class. Everything seems to work great, except that a) some of my numbers are showing up as squares in the table, and b) my `getPerimeter()` method that is being called in the table is not producing the same results as the same method called in a `System.out.println;` statement. Maybe the two problems stem from the same issue, I'm not sure.
Here is what I believe is the relevant code from my Triangle.java:

```
public String getAngleA()
{
    double a = sideA;
    double b = sideB;
    double c = sideC;
    angleA = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((c*c + b*b - a*a) / (2 * b * c)));
    return df.format(angleA);
}

public String getAngleB()
{
    double a = sideA;
    double b = sideB;
    double c = sideC;
    angleB = Math.toDegrees(Math.acos((a*a + c*c - b*b) / (2 * a* c)));
    return df.format(angleB);
}

public String getAngleC()
{
    angleC = 180 - (angleA + angleB);
    return df.format(angleC);
}

public String getPerimeter()
{
    perimeter = sideA + sideB + sideC;
    return df.format(perimeter);
}
```

And, here is all the code from my TriangleTester.java, as I have no clue where the problem lies:

```
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter X coordinate for the first corner of the triangle: ");
    int x1 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Y coordinate for the first corner of the triangle: ");
    int y1 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter X coordinate for the second corner of the triangle: ");
    int x2 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Y coordinate for the second corner of the triangle: ");
    int y2 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter X coordinate for the third corner of the triangle: ");
    int x3 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Y coordinate for the third corner of the triangle: ");
    int y3 = in.nextInt();

    Triangle myTri = new Triangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    String[] columnName = {"SIDES", "ANGLES", "PERIMETER", "AREA"};
    Object[][] data = {
            {"The length your triangle on side A is: " + myTri.getSideA(),
             "Angle A = " + myTri.getAngleA() + "\u00b0",
             "The perimeter of your triangle is: " + myTri.getPerimeter(),
             "The area of your triangle is: " + myTri.getArea()},
            {"The length your triangle on side B is: " + myTri.getSideB(),
             "Angle B = " + myTri.getAngleB() + "\u00b0",
             " ", " "},
            {"The length your triangle on side C is: " + myTri.getSideC(),
             " Angle C = " + myTri.getAngleC() + "\u00b0",
             " ", " "},
        };

    JTable table = new JTable(data, columnName);
    DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
    centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.LEFT );
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
    centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment( JLabel.CENTER );
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);

    frame.setSize(950,107);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setTitle("Your Triangle");
    frame.add(table.getTableHeader(),BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    frame.add(table);

    System.out.println(myTri.getP1() + "\n" +  myTri.getP2() + "\n" + myTri.getP3() + "\n");

    System.out.println("The length of triangle on side A is: " + myTri.getSideA());
    System.out.println("The length of triangle on side B is: " + myTri.getSideB());
    System.out.println("The length of triangle on side C is: " + myTri.getSideC() + "\n");

    System.out.println("Angle A is: " + myTri.getAngleA() + "\u00b0");
    System.out.println("Angle B is: " + myTri.getAngleB() + "\u00b0");
    System.out.println("Angle C is: " + myTri.getAngleC() + "\u00b0" + "\n");

    System.out.println("Perimeter is: " + myTri.getPerimeter() +"\n");

    System.out.println("Area is: " + myTri.getArea());
}
```

}

And lastly, here is a pic showing the table with the squares and the wrong perimeter output, and below that, you can see the console print out with the right numbers, so I know that my methods are correct.
[image]

Comment: An actually [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Your table's model should hold the numeric data, not the descriptive Strings. The renderer would then supply the strings if needed.

Comment: Don't use values which are calculated when another method relies on the result, for example , `getAngleC` relies on the calculations from `getAngleA` and `getAngleB`, but it has no means to know if these methods have been called.  These methods should return `double`, it's not there responsibility to format the result...

Comment: And don't mix command line a GUI, that's just annoying...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that the `getAngle()` methods were being called in my table before the `getSides()` methods were being run, so there were no values for the `getAngle()` methods to use. The all worked in my command line print out because all the methods were being run in "order," so the `getSides()` methods had all run before I called the first `getAngle()` method. Here's the fixed relevant code:

```
    double sideA = myTri.getSideA();
    double sideB = myTri.getSideB();
    double sideC = myTri.getSideC();
    double angleA = myTri.getAngleA();
    double angleB = myTri.getAngleB();
    double angleC = myTri.getAngleC();
    double perim = myTri.getPerimeter();
    double area = myTri.getArea();

    String[] columnName = {"SIDES", "ANGLES", "PERIMETER", "AREA"};
    Object[][] data = {
            {"Side A = " + df.format(sideA),
             "Angle A = " + df.format(angleA) + "\u00b0",
             "Perimeter = " + df.format(perim),
             "Area = " + df.format(area)},
            {"Side B = " + df.format(sideB),
             "Angle B = " + df.format(angleB) + "\u00b0",
             " ", " "},
            {"Side C = " + df.format(sideC),
             "Angle C = " + df.format(angleC) + "\u00b0",
             " ", " "}
        };
```

And, the reason I mixed command line output with a GUI output was because my GUI output wasn't working, and I needed a way to tell if my numbers were being calculated correctly. Clearly, I would not turn in or release a program that ran that way.